# JUnit: Mocking a JDBC write method in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application which writes to an SQL database. I have the block of code which writes to the DB wrapped in a feature flag condition as shown below:

```
public class TreatmentWriter implements ItemWriter<TreatmentData> {

    JdbcBatchItemWriter<TreatmentData> jdbcBatchItemWriter;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("shawQuery")
    private String shawQuery;

    @Autowired
    FeatureManager featureManager;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends TreatmentData> processedData) {
        for (TreatmentData data : processedData) {
            log.debug("Writing processed data: " + data.getTreatment());
        }
        try {
            if (featureManager.isActive(FeaturesToToggle.FEATURE_FLAG)) {
                log.debug("Query to update staging table: " + shawQuery);
                jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
                jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
                jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
                jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql(shawQuery);
                jdbcBatchItemWriter.write(processedData);
            } else {
                log.info("feature flag is disabled");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error writing to DB: {}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

For the unit tests I'm writing, I want to test the function of the feature flag and simply mock the writing to the DB. The way I have the tests setup however, the test fails saying that the `jdbcBatchItemWriter.write()` method call was never called

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TreatmentWriter.class})
public class TreatmentWriterTest {

    private MemoryAppender memoryAppender;

    @InjectMocks
    TreatmentWriter treatmentWriter;

    @Mock
    private FeatureManager featureManager;

    @Spy
    private JdbcBatchItemWriter<TreatmentData> jdbcBatchItemWriter;

    @Mock
    private SecretsBeans secretsBeans;

    @Mock
    private DataSource shawDataSourceCollectEtl;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.ally.cr");
        memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();
        memoryAppender.setContext((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory());
        logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        logger.addAppender(memoryAppender);
        memoryAppender.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void UT_whenFeatureFlagIsOn_writeToShaw() throws Exception {
        mockFeatureFlag(true); //setting flag to true

        Field shawQuery;
        shawQuery = treatmentWriter.getClass().getDeclaredField("shawQuery");
        shawQuery.setAccessible(true);
        shawQuery.set(treatmentWriter, "");

        TreatmentData treatmentData = createTreatmentData(); //generating test data
    
        treatmentWriter.write(Arrays.asList(treatmentData));
        assertThat(memoryAppender.search("Query to update Shaw staging table: ", Level.INFO).size()).isEqualTo(1);
        verify(jdbcBatchItemWriter).write(any(List.class));
    }
}
```

What can I do differently to allow this test to pass? I thought maybe by adding the line `doNothing().when(jdbcBatchItemWriter).write(any(List.class));` I can solve it, but I guess all that does is make sure nothing is returned during that method call (I know it already doesn't return anything).

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before going further on testing the feature flag, I suggest you fix your item writer implementation by extracting the delegate setup from the `write` method. Currently you are creating a new jdbcBatchItemWriter in each chunk of data, which is incorrect .

Comment: @shoaib-jpeg did you able to fix it & make it work ?